# "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL" using cURL?

Tags: url, curl

I have been trying to build this jarvas indoor positioning system for a school project and the code has been a real mess.(https://www.instructables.com/id/JARVAS-Indoor-Positioning-System/)

**Code**

```
curl -X POST '<a href="http://jarvas-api.herokuapp.com/location?x=1.0&y=0.5" 
rel="nofollow">jarvas-api.herokuapp.com/location?x=1.0&y=0.5</a>'
```

**Output:**

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54094362/608639), [curl (3) and “URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58801094/608639), [CURL error “URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL” when trying to pass variable as a part of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58059443/608639) and friends.